How can I get pm2 to report memory usage on the actual process?
When I run something like pm2 start app.js, I get the correct memory consumption. The PID in pm2 ls corresponds to the actual app's PID when using btop (a flavor of top/htop).
But when I run pm2 start "pnpm run dev" in a next.js app directory for example, it reports (launches?) a parent process that encapsulates the actual app, that has a different (much lower) memory consumption rate.
I have this question not only for next.js, but also for any other node app that I have to initiate with an npm (pnpm) script. What is the actual correct way of spawning such processes? Or is this the only way and I have to "deal with it"?
I took screenshots of what I've tried, comparing the pm2 ls and btop screens. I also highlighted the reported process on btop with red background, so it's easier to recognize
Here are the steps I've tried:
First, I've created a simple while loop app.js, and ran it using pm2 start app.js. Everything works as expected. The PID's match, and memory report is correct:



Then I switched to my next.js app dir, and tried pm2 start "pnpm run dev". Here you can see the actual app is using ~400MB, but pm2 shows the parent process, therefore a "wrong" memory usage:



Then I tried giving it proper arguments by doing pm2 start pnpm -- run dev. Same thing, but with 1 more extra nesting in the process chain:


--
I also tried pm2 start pnpm -- run -- dev, and pm2 start next dev, all resulting in similar behaviour (just changes in the nesting count). But I won't paste their screenshots here now to prevent clutter.
So, my question comes to:
If the thing that I want to run depends on some npm scripts that does complex stuff so I can't run the .js file directly, OR I don't have an app.js entry file that I can find with ease, what should I do to get no extra child processes in pm2 and have it bind itself to the "true process" so I can see the actual memory usage?
